# pushing a big float inside a tuple Julia

Tags: tuples, julia, bigfloat

I am trying to "push" a big float into a Tuple. But get following error:

```
# where test() is a function with big floats as values

store = Tuple{Any, Any}][]
for i in 1:10
    push!(store, test(i))
end
store
```

[image]

The error message mentions `convert()` as a solution, but I am not sure how to convert `test()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot push `BigFloat` into a container that accepts only `Tuples`. Your container has to accept `BigFloat`s instead, so initialize it with:

```
store = BigFloat[]
```

Also note that you could have just written:

```
store = test.(1:10)
```